# name 'objc' is not defined in pyttsx3.init()

Tags: python, init, pyttsx3

I'm working on a project for university, it's a voice assistant with python.
And in the debug when starting `pyttsx3.init()` I get the error `name 'objc' is not defined`.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2iB3.jpg)

I tried installing it from the source code by cloning the Github repository "git clone [https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc.git"](https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc.git%22)

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)